# Using eslint boolean prop naming rule on typescript interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have set up eslint with a rule `react/boolean-prop-naming` to flag boolean props that aren't named with 'is', 'has' etc. I can only get it to work on typescript component props when props are defined with a type rather than an interface. Is there a way this rule can work on interfaces that define props? I have an eslint rule to prefer interfaces.

My eslint rule:

```
'react/boolean-prop-naming': [
'error',
{
propTypeNames: ['bool', 'mutuallyExclusiveTrueProps'],
rule: '^((is|has|can|should)[A-Z]([A-Za-z0-9]?)+|(show|hide))'
},
],
```

Works fine, flags the naming:

```
type ButtonProps = {
wrongNamingForBooleanProp?: boolean
}

const Button = ({ wrongNamingForBooleanProp }: ButtonProps) => // etc
```

I want eslint to flag that the prop needs to be named properly here:

```
interface ButtonProps {
wrongNamingForBooleanProp?: boolean
}

const Button = ({ wrongNamingForBooleanProp }: ButtonProps) => // etc
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3285